# bootstrap collapse not retaining state after click event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap collapse. I have set up 3 different panels and each panel has add button. When I click on the add button (panel 2) then page get refreshed and it doesn't retain its state and as a result it shows panel 1.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1" id="col1">Stock Detail</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>Stock Name</td>
          <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbstockname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" ValidationGroup="gp2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbstockname" ErrorMessage="Stock Name Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          </td>
          <td>Client Name</td>
          <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddclientname" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
            </asp:DropDownList>
          </td>
          <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnaddstock" runat="server" ValidationGroup="gp2" Class="btn btn-primary" Text="ADD" OnClick="btnaddstock_Click" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <asp:GridView ID="gvstockdetail" class="table" runat="server" Width="500px">
      </asp:GridView>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is hard to answer without seeing the code from the click action.  Are you triggering an action that requires a page reload or could you do it via an ajax call?  If you cannot use ajax then you'll have to pass some value from your server that will communicate what the current page status needs to be.

Comment: @EricG  Actually, Click action which add Textbox value in the gridview.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you are using a server control.  With that there will always be a post back to the server.  Although some have had luck with

```
OnClientClick="return false;"
```

To prevent this refresh from happening you'll need to use an html element, not server element, and call your function using ajax.  Something like :

```
<input type="button" onclick="doAction()" />
```

And then have some ajax call to your server action:

```
var doAction = function() {
    //ajax call to your server
};
```

for more information on ajax calls please refer to the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/